# Is there a way to update status for different transactions done by a single user?

Tags: php, laravel

A user has Many Funds transactions and I want to update the status for one from pending to active when I click on the button.
I'm using this model:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('funds', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('accnumber')->nullable();
            $table->text('Remarks')->nullable();
            $table->text('acc_type')->nullable();
            $table->string('status')->default('pending');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }
```

Then I created the index.blade.php with with a foreach loop with buttons to update the default status from pending to active:

```
 @foreach($user as $user)
                          <tr>
                            <td> {{ $user->accno }} </td>
                            <td>{{ $user->accnumber }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $user->Remarks }} </td>
                            <td>{{ $user->acc_type }}</td>
                            <td>
                                <input data-id="{{$user->id}}" class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" {{ $user->status ? 'pending' : '' }}>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.card-body -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script>
            $(function() {
              $('.toggle-class').change(function() {
                  var status = $(this).prop('pending') == true ? 1 : 0; 
                  var user_id = $(this).data('id'); 

                  $.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
                      dataType: "json",
                      url: '/changeStatus',
                      data: {'status': status, 'user_id': user_id},
                      success: function(data){
                        console.log(data.success)
                      }
                  });
              })
            })
          </script>
```

I'm doing this from a tutorial online and I want to implement this for myself using this controller:

```
public function changeStatus(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::find($request->user_id);
        $funds = $user->Funds()->status;
        $funds = $request->status;
        $user->save();

        return response()->json(['success'=>'Status change successfully.']);
    }
```

Comment: how can you update a transaction if in the request you don't declare/pass the transaction id, or the identifier..

Comment: Please @AlbertoSinigaglia explain to me on what to do

Comment: add to the dom element data-user-id="{{$user->id}}" and data-transaction-id="{{$user->id}}" and add the transaction id to the request

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia please can you show me

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change status of all transactions of a single user:

```php
public function changeStatus(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::find($request->user_id);

    $user->Funds()->update(['status', $request->status]);

    return response()->json(['success' => 'Status changed successfully.']);
}
```